# Implementing sifting appender for log4j logger

Tags: maven, apache-spark, logging, log4j

[image]

I have projects with dependency as shown. The `own spark library` depends on `hadoop` library. Spark internally uses log4j for logging which I found difficult to change.

The `log4j` library has been excluded from all other projects and we use `logback` everywhere. I basically want to write `sifting appender` for the `log4j` logger.

Trans and IE are the projects where I write logs. At runtime, the logger is automatically set to `log4j`. However, since log4j library is excluded, I can't write any code to implement sifting appender.

How can I achieve this?